# "Run|Debug" Buttons Not Appearing on Visual Studio Code Java Programs

Tags: windows-10, java, visual-studio-code

A couple days ago I tried to initialize Visual Studio Code to be able to code in C++ using online instructions. They ended up not working at all, but I had edited some settings files (such as a .json file) in Visual Studio Code that I thought were all C++ specific. Afterwards, however, I no longer have the convenient "run | debug" buttons appearing above any "main" functions that I make in java files. In the past I used to be able to just click run and my program would run in the terminal at the bottom of the screen, as opposed to manually compiling and running the program using a terminal. I am running Windows 10. Does anyone know of any way to get these buttons back?

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koalz.png) of what the two buttons look like, appearing above any main functions in a java program.
I also found on the Visual Studio Code website a description of how to begin debugging, attached [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging), that describes that you need Language Support for Java(TM) by Redhat in order to get these two buttons. I have this extension downloaded, but it is still not working. Please help if you recognize this issue!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Make sure you have Java extensions, Java Debugger and other basic Java packages installed.

Then making sure the main function is formatted properly like below allowed the **Run|Debug** buttons to be seen.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, for troubleshooting, actually we need to have a reproduce steps which can understand what happened in your environment. So can you tell us what you have done to your settings first?

Second, there is a setting under common setting tab, that is Java>Debug>Settings>Enable Run Debug Code Lens. Please check whether this option has been unchecked. Although I think it should not be changed by you.